# ( loop insert into select ) vs ( export csv and bulk insert )

Tags: sql

I have a table that is 97gbs. I need to move this table to a new database with a different table schema.

I know there are a few options to do this but all options are always marked as the right answer. I do not know which solution is best suited for my situation. I need this data moved asap and can not afford to run into an error during transfer which option is best suited?

Writing to a file then bulk inserting that file to avoid log transactions
or
looping insert select top 20000

Comment: mssql sql server management studio

Comment: Am I incorrect in thinking you could use ALTER SCHEMA in this situation?

Comment: The data is on v1. We are pushing v2 live asap. V2 has completely separate table structures. Both need to be running at same time

Comment: have you tried creating the table on a different development server then attaching the table to the production database?

Comment: I used bcp which wrote my select statement to a text file then I bulk inserted the text file. Took less than 2 hours.